# NetInfo status update error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components

Running in iOs simulator I recive tihs error

ExceptionsManager.js:73 Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

While doing this.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isOnline: false
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.checkConnection);
}

componentWillUpdate(){
  NetInfo.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.checkConnection);
}

checkConnection = () => {
  NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then((data) => {
  console.log('refresh:', data);
    this.setState({
      isOnline: data <------ this is the line that affect me 
    })
  }); 
}
```

any idea why?

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the event listener in `componentWillUnmount` hook, not `componentWillUpdate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by ZeroBased_IX:

Do this instead:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
  NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange');
}
```

It's firing in that line because that's the line where you use the updated value into the rest of your codebase. Therefore breaking it at bundle compilation time.

Hope it was helpful!